# Installing customtkinter on Mac using home-brew

Tags: tkinter, customtkinter, python-3.11

I have installed python using homebrew on my Mac and installed customtkinter, to create a GUI for my python script, using pip in terminal. When I try to import customtkinter into my code it isn't recognized. Is there a way to install it through homebrew or to connect the installation that I did with pip? Apologies to all who read this, still a novice. Thank you!

I installed custontkinter for python through pip and it isn't being recognized when trying to import it to my python code file. Python though was installed used homebrew.